# AWS cron expression to run every month, every 3 months and once a year

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, yaml

I'm trying to create CRON expressions in YAML:

```
1. AWS Cron expression to run at 6AM every month: This what I have: cron(0 6 1 * ? *)
2. Run every 3 months
3. Run once a year in January
```

Can someone please help with this. Appreciate it greatly

Comment: Why has no-one disrupted cron with an English language parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

2. `cron(0 0 1 */3 * *)`
3. `cron(0 0 1 1 * *)`

Comment: I had to change some of it, but your answer was base. So it's good